# Ruby on rails , model or constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model with unit field.

- `rails g scaffold Car  speed:integer   unit:integer`

Units: `km/h`, `m/s`

Is it better to store unit in another model in  database or in constant in model?

`SPEED_UNITS = ['km/h', 'm/s']` in model or `rails g model SpeedUnit name:string` ?

I cannot recalculate units.
Once i have to write m/s , other times km/s it depend on what unit is delivered on special form made of paper.

The number of the units is 2, in feature might be 3 or 4  not more.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Why not use enums for it? Enums are fixed set of values for a field.

```
enum unit: [:kmph, :mps]
```

This way, your model will have utility methods like:

```
car.kmph? # is the unit kmph?
car.mps?  # is the unit mps?
car.kmph! # sets the unit as kmph
...
```

Refer [this guide](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for more details about enums.